# Inflating a layout in a fragment

Tags: android, android-view, layout-inflater

So I am finally learning Fragments after learning Activities. I am looking at a video tutorial. All of a sudden he changed the way a Fragment inflates a layout. Why does he have two different ways? The first way in FragmentA is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
}
```

Then the other way in FragmentB is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    if (savedInstanceState ==  null)
    {

    }
    else {
        savedInstanceState.getString("text");
        TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myText.setText(data);
    }
    return view;
}
```

So why did it change from return inflater.inflate to View view = inflater.inflate

Sorry for dumb question, but I can't find this answer on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the same,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

has to return a View.

And

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false)
```

returns a View as well.

In the second example he assigns the return value of inflater.inflate() to a View object, as he needs to loads some data and set it on this View object... then he returns it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lstindicators, container,
        false);
```

And return your view thats all! :D

jejeje... and if you want to change your current fragment for another chechk this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```